# Get data from first date on database till today

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to group my data by date and view it on chart. here my data example:

```
count                            created_at
-----                            ----------
 5                               2020/04/20
 4                               2020/04/21
 3                               2020/04/25
 9                               2020/04/28
```

i want my data when i fetch be like

```
count                            created_at
-----                            ----------
 5                               2020/04/20
 4                               2020/04/21
 0                               2020/04/22
 0                               2020/04/23
 0                               2020/04/24
 3                               2020/04/25
 0                               2020/04/26
 0                               2020/04/27
 9                               2020/04/28
```

when there is no data in that date it will shown 0. can u guys help me how to get it on laravel controller?

thanks before.

Comment: Please share your database structure in question

Comment: probaly you might need to run another loop if you don't have any record of a particular date

Answer (score 0):

@Alun here is an example of how you can do this:

```
SELECT `dateList`.`Date`,
    CASE WHEN `yt`.`date` IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE COUNT(`yt`.`id`) 
    END AS `amt`
FROM

-- this is the part you can copy/paste 
-- to be used to left join in a table of your choice 
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(
    SELECT DATE(`a`.`Date`) AS `Date`
    FROM (
        SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL (`a`.`a` + (10 * `b`.`a`) + (100 * `c`.`a`)) DAY AS `Date`
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS `a` UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS `a`
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `a` UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS `b`
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `a` UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS `c`
    ) AS `a` 
    WHERE `a`.`Date` BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND NOW()
) AS `dateList` 
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

LEFT JOIN `yourTable` AS `yt` ON `dateList`.`Date` = DATE(`yt`.`date`)
GROUP BY `dateList`.`Date`
ORDER BY `dateList`.`Date` ASC
```

Just sub your table name in place of `yourTable` in this query (modifying the date column name from your table replacing `yt.date` accordingly) and this will give you a list for every day of the month showing 0 for any day of the month that doesn't have any value.

As far as getting this to work using eloquent in a Laravel controller it might be possible but off the top of my head I don't know how you would do it. You could use this this raw SQL in the controller to accomplish what you want though.

[Here's an example of how it works in sql fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c2459/1)

Hope this helps!